# Creating a Java jar library to use on Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on developing a game for Android and I have a lot of the code written on a java application. I would like to use the classes and methods in the Java application within my Android application. I am using Eclipse to develop my application so I tried to create a Jar for the Java application By doing: `Right click project->Export->Jar` I then saved the jar somewhere and added the jar to my Android buildpath. When I try to use methods from that jar I get compilation errors because Eclipse cant find the methods. Am I supposed to have any import statements? The name of the package on my java app is (default package) so I am not sure what the import statement would be. I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I changed the package name of my application so that I could import the classes within it and that got rid of the compilation errors. When I try to run the project I now get  `NoClassDefFoundError` Could it be that I am exporting the jar for my Java application wrong?

Comment: Please, post Exceptions you got, to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Open Project `properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Report` tab.

Try to check jar check boxes,

see example:

[image]

To make sure that you created jar properly, here other snapshot of jar export:

[image]

Comment: So if I have a class called MyClass and a method within it that is called getData(), all I would have to do is call getData() within my Android app?

Comment: Not at all, 1st you import  your `MyClass` after initiate it (if your method is not static) like `MyClass mc = new MyClass()`, and after call method `ms.getData();`

Comment: I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError now

Comment: did you add jars to Libraries and select checkbox?

Comment: Yes, I added the jar as an external jar and then checked the box for order and export. I'm still getting a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Sounds like your jar doesnt contain classes. Did you try to open Jar file with ZIP and check what what is the content.

Comment: ON extracting I am able to see the .class file for the class I am trying to use.

Comment: I added snapshot of my export jar. Be sure that you have the same configuration

Answer (score 0):

Rename the package first. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Yes, you need to import the package inorder to use in a class. Else the compiler will not identify the codes. Import the jar into build path and import the package into the Java code as :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly you exporting a Java .jar (built using Java compiler)? As far as I know Android does not understand Java bytecode though the compiler for Android understands Java source code.

I'd suggest you just put all that source files in the Android project and compile them there, hopefully you aren't using functions that Android API does not have.